# Storing multiple values in a tfrecord feature

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

| image_id | class_1_rle | class_2_rle | class_3_rle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0002cc93b.jpg` |  | `29102 12 29346 24...` |  |
| `0007a71bf.jpg` | `18661 28 18863 82...` |  |  |
| `000a4bcdd.jpg` | `131973 1 132228 4...` |  | `229501 11 229741 33...` |

I am trying to create the `tfrecords` using the above table. I need to get together the `rle` (Run Length Encoding) feature in the form of `rle` per class. Eg. the feature in the final `tfrecord` looks like

```
img_id: b'0002cc93b.jpg'
rle: [b'1 0'  b'29102 12 29346 24...'  b'1 0']

img_id: b'000a4bcdd.jpg'
rle: [b'131973 1 132228 4...'  b'1 0'  b'229501 11 229741 33...']
```

The `rle` feature should contain the `rles` for all the 3 masks for the corresponding image as strings and empty `rle` should be encoded as `'1 0'`

I tried using a list. But it gives the following error

```
TypeError: ['29102 12 29346 24 29602 24 29858 24 30114 24 30370 24 30626 24 30882 24 31139 23 31395 23 31651 23 has type list, but expected one of: bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an overall [solution](https://www.kaggle.com/reyvaz/siim-pneumothorax-tfrecs) that suits my case.

The specific [solution](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/keras-flowers-data#4) of storing multiple values in a feature.

Used pandas to replace empty rles in the df as`'1 0'`

A function to grab the rles corresponding to the image from the df.

```
def rle_class_1(image_id):
    temp_df = df['class_1_rle'][df['image_id'] == image_id]
    for rle in temp_df:
        rle_tensor = tf.constant(rle)
        return rle_tensor.numpy()
```

Similar functions for class_2 and class_3.

Create tfrecord

```
paths_dict = dict(zip(file_ids, file_paths))

def _bytestring_feature(list_of_bytestrings):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=list_of_bytestrings))

def _int_feature(list_of_ints):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=list_of_ints))

def image_bits_from_id(image_id):
    image = Image.open(paths_dict[image_id])
    image = tf.constant(image)
    image_bits = tf.image.encode_jpeg(image, optimize_size=True, chroma_downsampling=False)
    image_bits = image_bits.numpy()
    return image_bits

def create_tfrec_example(image_id):

    image = image_bits_from_id(image_id) 
    rle_1 = rle_class_1(image_id)
    rle_2 = rle_class_2(image_id)
    rle_3 = rle_class_3(image_id)
    
    feature = {
        'image': _bytestring_feature([image]),
        'img_id': _bytestring_feature([image_id.encode()]),
        'rle': _bytestring_feature([rle_1, rle_2, rle_3])
        }

    tfrec_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    return tfrec_example
```

Parse and view record

```
def parse_tfrecord_fn(example):
    features = {
        'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), 
        'img_id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }
    features['rle'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.string)

    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, features)
    example["image"] = tf.io.decode_jpeg(example["image"], channels=3)
    return example

raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(TFREC[0])   # TFREC is a shard
parsed_dataset = raw_dataset.map(parse_tfrecord_fn)

for features in parsed_dataset.take(5):
    for key in features.keys():
        if key != "image":
            print(f"{key}: {features[key]}")

    print(f"Image shape: {features['image'].shape}")
    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
    plt.imshow(features["image"].numpy())
    plt.show()
```

Output

```
img_id: b'0002cc93b.jpg'
rle: [b'29102 12 29346 24 29602 24 29858 24... '
 b'1 0' b'1 0']
Image plot
```

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this in 3 simple steps, although it is hard to say what you actually intend to do without further details:

**Create and parse data**:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import tabulate
import numpy as np

d = {'image_id': ['0002cc93b.jpg', '0007a71bf.jpg', '000a4bcdd.jpg'], 
     'class_1_rle': ['', '18661 28 18863 82...', '131973 1 132228 4...'], 
     'class_2_rle': ['29102 12 29346 24...', '', ''], 
     'class_3_rle': ['', '', '229501 11 229741 33...']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
default_value = '1 0'
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', default_value, regex=True)
print(df.to_markdown())

image_ids = np.asarray(df.pop('image_id'))
rle_classes = df.to_numpy()
image_ids_shape = image_ids.shape
rle_classes_shape = rle_classes.shape

image_ids = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'))(image_ids).ravel()
rle_classes = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'))(rle_classes).ravel()
```

```
|    | image_id      | class_1_rle          | class_2_rle          | class_3_rle            |
|---:|:--------------|:---------------------|:---------------------|:-----------------------|
|  0 | 0002cc93b.jpg | 1 0                  | 29102 12 29346 24... | 1 0                    |
|  1 | 0007a71bf.jpg | 18661 28 18863 82... | 1 0                  | 1 0                    |
|  2 | 000a4bcdd.jpg | 131973 1 132228 4... | 1 0                  | 229501 11 229741 33... |
```

**Create tfrecord**:

```py
def bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value = value))

def create_example(image_ids, rle_classes):

  feature = {'img_id': bytes_feature(image_ids),
             'rle': bytes_feature(rle_classes)}
  example = tf.train.Example(features = tf.train.Features(feature = feature))
  return example

test_writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter('data.tfrecords')

example = create_example(image_ids, rle_classes)
test_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
test_writer.close()
```

**Read tfrecord**:

```py
def parse_tfrecord(example):
  feature = {'img_id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([image_ids_shape[0]], tf.string),
             'rle': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([rle_classes_shape[0], rle_classes_shape[1]], tf.string)}
  parsed_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature)
  return parsed_example

serialised_example = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('data.tfrecords')
parsed_example_dataset = serialised_example.map(parse_tfrecord)
parsed_example_dataset = parsed_example_dataset.flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
for features in parsed_example_dataset:
  print(features['img_id'], features['rle'])
```

```
tf.Tensor(b'0002cc93b.jpg', shape=(), dtype=string) tf.Tensor([b'1 0' b'29102 12 29346 24...' b'1 0'], shape=(3,), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'0007a71bf.jpg', shape=(), dtype=string) tf.Tensor([b'18661 28 18863 82...' b'1 0' b'1 0'], shape=(3,), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'000a4bcdd.jpg', shape=(), dtype=string) tf.Tensor([b'131973 1 132228 4...' b'1 0' b'229501 11 229741 33...'], shape=(3,), dtype=string)
```

Comment: I also have to store the actual images in the tfrecord. Would it be feasible to vectorize and flatten the images as well?

Comment: I found a solution that scales better for my case. Posting here soon.